# Display Char with TextView

Tags: android, textview, char, listadapter

I need to Display the `songtitle2.get(i).charAt(0)` in the textview.  I have already populated the list view with song names and i want to put the dividers in everytime the song names first letter changes.

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.song,songtitle);

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

then i call this method to get the divider

```
private void alphebetdividers(ArrayList<String> songtitle2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dividerss = (TextView)findViewById(R.layout.song);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while( j < songtitle.size()-1){
            if(songtitle2.get(i).charAt(0) == songtitle2.get(i+1).charAt(0)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), songtitle2.get(i).charAt(0) + "== " + songtitle2.get(i+1).charAt(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{


                      //////DISPLAY CHAR WITH TEXTVIEW//////
            }
      j++;
      i++;

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply convert the `char` to a `String` with:

```
String songName = 'My Song Name'
char my_char = songName.chatAt(0);
String newString = new String(char);
```

Or just get the substring with:

```
String songName = 'My Song Name'
String newString = songName.subString(0,1);
```

Then set the label on the textview with:

```
textView.setText(newString);
```

Comment: slayton i am getting a force close when i do that .. i think it has to do with the fact that im trying to display a text on top of the ones that already populate the list view here                      adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.song,songtitle);
setListAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 1):

You can define like

```
char[] ch = { 'a', 'b' };

textView.setText(ch, 0, 2);
```